# Does MySQL's ALTER TABLE ADD PRIMARY KEY also cluster the data?

Tags: mysql

Does MySQL's ALTER TABLE ADD PRIMARY KEY also cluster the data, or do I need to create the table from scratch with the primary key to get the clustering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the engine. MyISAM doesn't do it, but InnoDB does. If you're using MyISAM you can cluster the table using the [ALTER TABLE ORDER BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html#id4262072) syntax.